# Getting page ID inside loop

Tags: loop, page-template

I have a page template which has a loop to show blog posts. Inside the loop, there is `get_template_part('content', 'custom')` function to include the template (content-custom.php) which shows blog post content. Is it possible to get current page ID inside `content-custom.php` file?

Comment: content-custom.php is not a page, it is basically just the loop that is removed from its original place and added into a separate template.

Comment: @PieterGoosen Yes, you are right. But I want to get the ID of a page which is including `content-custom.php` file by `get_template_part()` method.

Comment: Why do you need the page ID

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use all [template tags](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags) inside this file, so to get the ID, just use [`get_the_ID()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_ID) (or [`the_ID()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_ID) to output it).

`get_the_ID()` will retrieve the numeric ID of the current post. It has no parameters and returns the ID of the current post.

`the_ID()` will display the numeric ID of the current post. It also has no parameters.

If you want to access the ID of page which contains your custom loop, then you could do it like this:

### Solution 1 (simple, but not very nice way with global variable)

In your page template:

```
<?php
    global $parent_page_id;
    $parent_page_id = get_the_ID();
    $paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
    $args = array( 'post_type' => 'post', 'paged' => $paged );
    $temp = $wp_query;
    $wp_query = null;
    $wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );
    $wp_query->query( $args );
?>

<?php if ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
    <?php while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>
    <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'custom' ); ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

<?php else : ?>
    <?php get_template_part( 'no-results', 'index' ); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

And in your post-content template:

```
...
global $parent_page_id; // now you can use parent_page_template variable
...
```

### Solution 2 (nicer way with custom query)

In your page template:

```
<?php
    $paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
    $args = array( 'post_type' => 'post', 'paged' => $paged );
    $my_custom_query = new WP_Query( $args );
?>

<?php if ( $my_custom_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
    <?php while ( $my_custom_query->have_posts() ) : $my_custom_query->the_post(); ?>
    <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'custom' ); ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

<?php else : ?>
    <?php get_template_part( 'no-results', 'index' ); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

And in your post-content template:

```
...
... $wp_query->queried_object_id; // it will contain object queried in original wp_query
...
```

Comment: Thanks Krzysiek, but I want to get the current page ID, not the blog post ID.

Comment: OK, so you have a page, which contains custom posts loop and inside that loop you want to access the ID of that page?

Comment: Yes, exactly...

Comment: How does that custom loop look like?

Comment: Here is the code. [link](http://pastebin.com/Nkyps609)

Comment: Simply define a variable outside your custom loop for your current post id that you can re-use later

Comment: But I can't access this variable inside the template which I'm including (in this case, content-custom.php)

Comment: Use a regular include instead of the get_template_part: include(locate_template('content-custom.php')); This way the variables are passed, so you can re-use them in your template.

Comment: Well, few bad habits in there. 1. Don't use regular include (it's a very bad practice which breakes child themes). 2. Don't modify global `wp_query` to make custom queries. Use your own query instance (then you would be able to access global wp_query inside that loop).

Answer (score 10):

Per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3127776/383847) you could use [`get_queried_object_id()`](http://wpseek.com/get_queried_object_id/) which isn't yet in the Codex, but is related to [`get_queried_object()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_queried_object)

```
$page_id = get_queried_object_id();
```

Comment: You really went and dug far and across borders. +1 for miss viking :)

Comment: Thanks @PieterGoosen, but I didn't have to dig far... it was the first result I found in Google.

Comment: @helgatheviking But it won't work, since he modifies global `$wp_query` object. Am I overlooking something?

Comment: @KrzysiekDróżdż I don't think you're overlooking anything. I didn't see mention of that in the question and anyway it seems like a bad idea to modify the global `$wp_query`.

Comment: @helgatheviking Yes, it is a bad idea, but he does it anyway :)

Comment: @KrzysiekDróżdż I still don't see where he says he does this? But, if an OP wishes to ignore suggestions to not modify globals, then the OP must be willing to accept that some core functions may not work as expected.

Comment: @helgatheviking In comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/144471/getting-page-id-inside-loop/144484?noredirect=1#comment207844_144472

Comment: @KrzysiekDróżdż I don't interpret that comment to mean he is modifying global variables, just that `get_the_ID()` isn't returning what he is after. Guess we can't know until the OP comes back to test my answer.

Comment: If someone has a solution on working pagination without using main query, please show me. I know that messing with main query is not cool, but I can't get working pagination without using it.

Comment: @SodbilegGansukh It seems like you are now asking a new question and should post it as such. And next time, explain what you are doing with the main query so people can give you better advice/answers. I still don't know what you are doing to the main query so I can't comment, but I believe I have answered the question as originally asked.

Answer (score 1):

To get page id you can use global post.

```
global $post;
echo "pageid: ".$post->ID;
```

Above will retrive current page id not post id.

Comment: I did some Google search before posting here, and tried that already. This is giving me the current blog post ID, but not the page ID inside the template. Thank you shahpranaf.

Comment: can you provide front end link ?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't. It's on my local machine.

Comment: NP. can you printr $post here?

Comment: Here it is. [link](http://pastebin.com/kHGgUYKv)

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1:** (Bad Solution)

```
$p = $GLOBALS['wp_the_query']->get_queried_object_id(); 
//$p will be your page id
```

Note: You should never use the the global wp_the_query object.

**EDIT:** if you haven't tampered the global wp_query object, ie: you haven't used query_posts() etc. then helgatheviking's solutions will work: 
code:

```
 get_queried_object_id(); 
or 
$GLOBAL['wp_query']->get_queried_object_id();
```

**Solution 2:** Like  passatgt suggested in the comment, you can store the page id outside the loop and access it inside the loop. the scope issue of accessing it in the template part file can be soloved by declaring it global.

Code:

```
//1. in the template file befor the loop 

global $myglobal_page_id;
$mygloba_page_id = get_the_ID();
//you can start the loop here
get_template_part('content', 'custom');

// 2. in the template part file 

global $myglobal_page_id; //inside the loop or otherwise

//this will have your page_id
```

**Explanation#Solution 1:**

Once inside the loop, the global post object is set to your current post. 
hence when you call the the_ID(), get_the_ID() (which used get_post() function), you will get the id of current post, and not the main post.

so you need to access the main wp_the_query object (which is a copy of the main query object used for resetting the query ref: wp_reset_query()), as it contains your original query.

Comment: Hmm, I don't think it would work. He modifies global `$wp_query` in his code.

Comment: it will work, you will be directly accessing the wp_the_query, it's a copy of the main query stored by wordpress.

Comment: am editting my answer with more options.

Comment: This is not a proper answer. Please edit your answer and add an explanation to what your code does and how it works

Comment: am typing it..:P